# Convert "%y-%m-%d" with strptime() in C fails

Tags: c, strptime

I'm trying to convert the character string "2011-12-12" into a time value using strptime. Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

According to the docs:

> The format is composed of zero or more directives. Each directive is composed of one of the following: one or more white-space characters (as specified by isspace()); an ordinary character (neither '%' nor a white-space character); or a conversion specification.

```
if( strptime(date, "%y-%m-%d", &tm) != NULL)
```

Comment: Is `%-` a conversion specification?  (I think maybe you just want `-`)

Comment: I made a mistake.. Initally I tried with -, changed it to %- for testing.. both cases failed.. I forgotten to remove the '%' when posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime).  The `%y` specifier is for two-digit years, without the century, whereas `%Y` is for the full year, including the century.  When you use `%y` with your input string, it parses the year as `20`, and then since the rest of the string (`11-12-12`) doesn't match `-%m-%d`, parsing fails.

Either change your format string to use `%Y` (recommended), or change your input to use two-digit dates (strongly **not** recommended).